# Making a recursive antlr4 rule greedy

Tags: antlr4

I'd like to have a grammar where a `filter` can be either an `operation` or any number of filters joined by `|`. My grammar is like this:

```
filter
  : filter ('|' filter)+  #pipedFilter
  | OPERATION             #operation
  ;


OPERATION
  : [a-z]+
  ;
```

(This is a simplified example, there will be other ways of grouping filters which have different precedence than piping)

On input like `xxx|yyy` this works fine, we get:

```
FILTER: [
  OPERATION: xxx,
  OPERATION: yyy
]
```

But for input of `xxx|yyy|zzz` we get:

```
FILTER: [
  OPERATION: xxx,
  FILTER: [
    OPERATION: yyy,
    OPERATION: zzz
  ]
]
```

and I would like

```
FILTER: [
  OPERATION: xxx,
  OPERATION: yyy,
  OPERATION: zzz
]
```

Both interpretations seem valid, but I would like the second. It seems to me that the problem is that the `#pipedFilter` rule isn't being applied as greedily as it could be.  Is my understanding correct here? What can be the fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hasn't to do with greedyness. The default in ANTLR4 is to match as much as possible in one rule.

The output structure you get is dictated by your grammar. Don't make `filter` a recursive rule if you don't want a tree. What speaks against writing filter like so:

```
filter:
    OPERATION (PIPE OPERATION)?
```

If you absolutely need filters containing filters then, I'm afraid, there's no way around a tree like result.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  "don't make a recursive rule if you don't want a tree" is a useful way to think about it. I have done similar to your suggestion with different precedence operators as different rules rather than trying to put everything into one rule.

Comment: *The default in ANTLR4 is to match as much as possible in one rule.* I still don't understand why this rule doesn't result in the `filter` rule matching as many piped `OPERATION`s as it can in a single `filter`... What parsing rule causes the hierarchical result to be preferred over the flat one (given that both are allowed by this grammar)? Naively, to me, "matching as much as possible" seems like it should prefer the flat result.

Comment: Ah, I think I see it - in parsing the `filter` rule, the parser first of all descends into one of the `filter`s in the rule definition, and *matches as much as it can there* (while ensuring that the top level `filter` pattern can still be matched). Is that the idea?